# Express GET request works on local server, but not on hosted site

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, get, ejs

I am working to flesh out my portfolio site, and I am trying to add a link in a project block to a recent web project. I developed this side project in isolation from my portfolio site documents, but now that it's ready to show, I want to host it off of the same domain as my portfolio.

The problem I'm having is that the get request to the side project page won't show the index.ejs file. The format of the code at this moment represents just a simple test to get it to work at a basic level. This code works just fine on a local server, but when uploaded to run off my droplet, it shows the "Cannot GET /page" error.

Both my index.html and index.ejs files are hosted in a views folder. I have tried multiple variations of the filepath for the index.ejs file to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated!

server.js file

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/page', function(req, res) {
  res.render(__dirname + '/views/index.ejs');
});

const listener = app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Your app is listening on port ' + listener.address().port);
});
```

html file

```
        <div class="project-tile">
          <form action="/page" method="GET">
            <button type="submit">Link</button>
          </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Double check if your source code for the express server is updated on the droplet, and also ensure that you have restarted the nodejs process running the code on the droplet to make sure that it is using the latest version of your code.

Comment: Restarting the nodejs process on the droplet server did the trick! Thanks for the help @willi123yao. However, now when I add new require statements to my server.js file, the server throws a 502 Gateway error. Do you have any suggestions as to what that might be?

Comment: Have you installed the dependencies what you have require in your file. Add dependencies to package.json and install them and restart the nodejs process